# I watched an entire season together/in a row

Tags: word-usage

If someone watches all the episodes of a season in a row, what will be a natural way to express this:

> I watched an entire season **in a row**.
>
> I watched an entire season **together**

What sounds natural "in a row" or "entire" with a season? And does "whole" instead of "**entire**" with "**season**" sound natural?

> I watched a whole season .......

Answer (score 2):

Consider **...in one go** or **...in one sitting**.

From https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+go:

> **at/in one go** *(British English)*
>
> in one single action; all at the same time: 
>   I don’t think I’ll be able to solve all the problems at one go. He ate the whole cake in one go.
>   See also: go, one

*In one go* is as natural as I can think of to this native British English-speaker.

*In one sitting* might be more natural to American English-speakers, but *I* usually consider this one more-related to eating lots of food, rather than watching lots of TV.

*Whole season* and *Entire season* are both fine.

If you want to use **in a row**, consider changing the sentence so that the subject is plural.  **All episodes** is a good substitute.

- *"I watched the whole season in one go."*
- *"I watched the entire season in one go."*
- *"I watched all episodes in a row."*
- *"I watched all episodes, one after the other."*

Comment: So isn't "in one go" common in AmE? Will Americans be more likely to use "in one sitting"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish : Couldn't say for certain, as I'm not an American.  I would understand either; I expect they would too, but as to whether it is *common*, you'd need to ask them.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+one+go%2Cin+one+sitting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20sitting%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20sitting%3B%2Cc0) is interesting, though -- I'd have thought it the other way around.

Comment: This is just English. There is no AmE or BrE thing here. In short, what is missing here is the verb: to binge watch a series. That is what people are saying nowadays for this. But this answer is ***fine***.

Comment: @Lambie : "binge-watch" *was* there--in someone else's comment to the question--until about 30s ago.  I was affording the commenter the chance to answer themselves, and let it stand on its own merit.  Has obviously been removed by the comment police, though...

Comment: No worries at all.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't realized this was defined as an actual word: [**binge-watch**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/binge-watch):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    : to watch many or all episodes of (a TV series) in rapid succession
>   // Even those of us who have bundled TV and broadband-Internet subscriptions from telephone or cable companies increasingly use them to *binge-watch* Netflix shows like Orange Is the New Black on an iPad … rather than flip through 500 channels to find nothing on.
>   //— Rana Foroohar

I would have said this was more informal before I thought to look it up, but it seems as if it's entered modern culture.

In short:

> I *binge-watched* the entire season of the show one night.

Comment: That's fine, but I voted for the other answer as it's closer to the question.

Comment: And will it be okay to use "I watched an entire season all at once."

Comment: And what about "I read an entire novel (ate a whole cake) all at once. (in one sitting)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish The verb is *binge-watch*. You can't do that with a book or a cake. It might be possible to say that you [*binged*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/binge) or *binged on* those things, but that would be less common, and it might be misunderstood without specific context. Also, it would have slightly different meaning.

Comment: @JasonBassford will it be okay to use: "I watched an entire season all at once." (For "binge watching".)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish That's fine too, but that's how this question started. When talking about watching an entire season at once, in one go, without stop, etc.,  the common verb now is *binge-watched*, which will always be the most natural way of saying it.

Comment: Some say that "at once" doesn't sound natural and rather it should be "in one sitting" or "binge-watch". Do you agree that "all at once" means something like *watching all the episodes at the same time*? "*I watched an entire season all at once*"